# Need an alternative to join on the same table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch 
Dept name from the below table for every row.
[[image 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7VLY.jpg)

```
Employee | Manager | Dept
---------+---------+-------------
Santosh  | Gyan    |
Rahul    |         | HR
Suresh   | Gyan    |
Gyan     |         | Technology
```

- Every manager is also an Employee.
- IF Dept name is not available for an Employee, then I have to search his manager in Employee column and find his Dept.

Attached is the expected output.
[[image 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4arb1.jpg)

```
Employee | Manager | Dept
---------+---------+------------
Santosh  | Gyan    | Technology
Rahul    |         | HR
Suresh   | Gyan    | Technology
Gyan     |         | Technology
```

Have tried Right joining the same table, it gives the result but takes too much of time on a large table. So please suggest an alternative way.

Comment: The real world depth of organisation does not describe well in your example

Comment: Does your table is storing employee names for employee and manager ? That is a bad idea. Try to create an Primary key column with an integer data type for every employee and replace your manager name with manager id. Searching and joining will be faster in integer data type and also this will make your table more consistent. Even you can keep the department in separate table and map the id to the employee table for keeping the tables normalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like:

```
SELECT 
    Employee, 
    Manager,
    CASE WHEN Dept = '' THEN (
        SELECT t.Dept 
        FROM yourTable t 
        WHERE t.Employee = yourTable.Manager
    )
    ELSE Dept
    END As Dept
FROM 
    yourTable;
```

**[[SQL Fiddle Demo]](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93b83/1)**

This query is just as a SQL translation of what you say ;).

Answer (score 1):

To gain the Query performance u could use Union All instead.

```
    SELECT EMPLOYEE, DEPT FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPT IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT E.EMPLOYEE, EM.DEPT FROM EMPLOYEE E
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE EM ON E.MANAGER = EM.MANAGER
    AND E.DEPT IS  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
SELECT e.Employee, e.Manager, COALESCE(e.Dept, e1.Dept) Dept
FROM Employees e 
LEFT JOIN Employees e1 ON e1.Employee = e.Manager
```

OR:

```
SELECT e.Employee, e.Manager, COALESCE(e.Dept, t.Dept) Dept
FROM Employees e 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT dept FROM Employees e1 WHERE e1.employee = e.manager) t
```

Comment: If you have a large table with given structure, create an index on employee and manager columns and try with the above methods that @Suraz suggested.+1 from my side.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a left join on a distinct list

```
Declare @YourTable table (Employee varchar(50),Manager varchar(50),Dept varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Santosh','Gyan',''),
('Rahul','','HR'),
('Suresh','Gyan',''),
('Gyan','','Technology')

Select A.Employee
      ,A.Manager
      ,Dept = Isnull(B.Dept,A.Dept)
 From  @YourTable A
 Left Join (Select Distinct Employee,Dept from @YourTable Where Dept<>'') B
   on  A.Manager=B.Employee
```

Or even

```
Select A.Employee
      ,A.Manager
      ,Dept = case when A.Dept='' then B.Dept else A.Dept end
 From  @YourTable A
 Outer Apply (Select Dept from @YourTable Where Employee=A.Manager) B
```

Returns

```
Employee    Manager Dept
Santosh     Gyan    Technology
Rahul               HR
Suresh      Gyan    Technology
Gyan                Technology
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT e.Employee, e.Manager, ISNULL(e.Dept, em.Dept)
FROM Employees e 
    LEFT JOIN Employees em ON em.Employee = e.Manager
        AND e.Dept = ''
```